# How to use LINQ to adjust result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

From this LINQ:

```
var inspectionItems = inspArchive.Select(x => x.InspectionItems);
```

I get this result in inspectionItems :

[image]

My question is how can I make using LINQ in elegant way to make from inspectionItems result above one array distincted by Id.

Like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) LINQ method:

```
var inspectionItems = inspArchive.SelectMany(x => x.InspectionItems);
```

If you only want distinct items by a particular property, then you can either implement an equality comparer to see if your inspection classes are equal, then call `.Distinct(myInspectionEqualityComparer)` at the end of your method chain, or you can do this:

```
var distinctInspectionItems = inspArchive.SelectMany(x => x.InspectionItems)
                                         .GroupBy(i => i.Id)
                                         .Select(group => group.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code, I think you want to use `SelectMany` and `Distinct` ?

```
var inspectionItems = inspArchive.SelectMany(x => x.InspectionItems).Distinct();
```

Comment: (although I think the syntax for distinct takes something else?)

Comment: Distinct does not, in fact, take a `Func<T>` as a parameter. You need to either implement an equality comparer or use `GroupBy` and `Select`.

Comment: or just use `Distinct()` with no args and hope your type is already comparable/etc to make the built in distinct work?

Comment: Nope, `.Distinct()` by itself uses `Object.GetHashCode()` to compare items, which will not work in this scenario where he only wants to check the ID.

Comment: that's why i didn't say "implements comparable", i said "is already comparable/etc to make the built in distinct work".  if his underlying types implemented `GetHashCode` as `return this.Id.hashCode()` or something else, this might work.  it's a long shot, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but check if this works for you:

```
var inspectionItems = inspArchive.SelectMany(x => x.InspectionItems)
                                 .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                                 .Select(g => g.First())
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: The default equality comparer will be applied when using `.Distinct()`, which uses `GetHashCode()`. This will not return distinct results based on the ID alone.